# How do I fadeout the current slide in HTML in Codecademy?

Tags: html

```
var main = function() {

 $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {   
    $('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
});

$('.arrow-next').click(function() {
  var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
  var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();

  var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
  var nextDot = currentDot.next();

  if(nextSlide.length == 0) {
    nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
    nextDot = $('.dot').first();
  }

  $('.arrow-prev').click(function() {
    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();

    if(prevSlide.length==0) {
        prevSlide=$('.slide').last();
    }

  currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
  nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

  currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
  nextDot.addClass('active-dot');
});
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

When I try to submit this code in Codecademy, I get this error: "Try again, remember to fadeout the current slide. I have done exactly what it says in the "hint" section, but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Can you provide JSFiddle, also as I know Codeacademy have some bugs, it happens you have 100% correct but it wont let you proceed (don't know for your case).

Comment: I guessed so. because it is all correct what I am doing. thanks.

Comment: Is that the exact code that you are using? Then one reason that it doesn't pass is that it won't run at all. You are missing a `});` somewhere, your starting and ending brackets doesn't match.